# Beginner. Python Lists. Int's & Strings

Tags: python, list

```
def changeList(myList):
    myList = myList[3:]
    new_list = []

    count = -1
    for line in myList:
        count += 1
        new_list += [list(myList[count])]

    count1 = -1
    for i in new_list:

         count1 += 1
         count2 = -1

         for j in i:

             count2 += 1

             if j == "-":
                 new_list[count1][count2] = 0 #- 0 - Can't go there.
             elif j == "|":
                 new_list[count1][count2] = 0 #| 0 - Can't go there.
             elif j == "+":
                 new_list[count1][count2] = 0 #+ 0 - Can't go there.
             elif j == " ":
                 new_list[count1][count2] = 1 #Blank - 1 for empty cell.

    for i in new_list:

       print(i)

    return new_list
```

Why when I do this...

```
print(type(new_list[0][0]))
```

it returns the type as string? I need it to be an int like I assigned it too. When I print the new_list out. It doesn't show the contents as ["0","0",....etc] it shows them as [0,0,0...etc] they must be integers. What am I missing here. Thanks.

The parameter I'm entering into the function (myList) looks like this...

```
['10 20', '1 1', '10 20', '-----------------------------------------', '|     |       | | |       |     | |     |', '|-+ +-+-+ + + + + + +-+ + + +-+-+ + + +-|'...etc
```

And I want to go

```
new_list[0][0] = 3
```

But it won't let me!?

Comment: First off fix the indents - its impossible to read that code, next show how you are calling the function - i.e. what data are you passing to it

Comment: I fixed what you were asking for.

Comment: So the only way I could reproduce the list type producing "str" was when placing the print(type(my_list[0][0])) before the conversion to the ints.  As well, where is it "not letting you" set new_list[0][0] to 3, because that could be indicative of another issue all together.

Comment: Also, just as a code review type thing, you're really hamfisting some things together, I would suggest you look into the enumerate function for your for loops (it'll make them more pythonic and easier to read/debug).  Look into list comprehensions for building out your first pass on new_list, again, readability and pythonic-ness.

Comment: Yes, where are you printing the type and what error do  you get in the assignment?

Comment: I then use another function that takes new_list as a parameter. This new function changes the entries in new_list. I'm trying to change new_list[0][0] = 3 and it gives me the error 'str' object does not support item assignment.

Comment: So test it, right before you do the assignment, do a print of new_list, see if something in there is showing a list, and update your answer with the information.

Comment: But, isn't it not working because the contents of new_list are strings? If they were int's the assignment would perform correctly??

Answer (score -3):

myList, your input has string values.

```
myList = ['|     |       | | |       |     | |     |', '|-+ +-+-+ + + + + + +-+ + + +-+-+ + + +-|']
```

You convert the list to a 2d list.

```
new_list = [list(i) for i in myList]
```

Now we loop changing string values to integers.

```
count1 = -1
for i in new_list:
    count1 += 1
    count2 = -1

    for j in i:

        count2 += 1
        if j == "-":
            new_list[count1][count2] = 0 #- 0 - Can't go there.
        elif j == "|":
            new_list[count1][count2] = 0 #| 0 - Can't go there.
        elif j == "+":
            new_list[count1][count2] = 0 #+ 0 - Can't go there.
        elif j == " ":
            new_list[count1][count2] = 1 #Blank - 1 for empty cell.
         # else: # Currently you don't have an else, so that makes me guess that you are getting a value you are not expecting.
         else:
             print("ERROR: THERE IS AN ISSUE HERE")
             new_list[count1][count2] = -1
```

I don't know your exact input you could have binary data. If that is your case then you will have to encode/decode accordingly.

I did not experience your problem.

```
print(type(new_list[0][0]))
<class "int">
```

So you are getting an unexpected input value.

You can try to force an int.

```
int(new_list[0][0])
```

If you need more information on what is being printed then use the repr method.

```
print(repr(new_list[0][0]))
```

enumeration like Jeff Langemeier suggested.

```
for i, li in enumerate(new_list):
    for j, item in enumerate(li):
        if item == "-":
            li[j] = 0 #- 0 - Can't go there.
        elif item == "|":
            li[j] = 0 #| 0 - Can't go there.
        elif item == "+":
            li[j] = 0 #+ 0 - Can't go there.
        elif item == " ":
            li[j] = 1 #Blank - 1 for empty cell.
        else:
            print("ERROR")
            li[j] = -1
```

Comment: I think the op is asking about `print(type(new_list[0][0]))`

Comment: That is why I answered with the hint on repr and int conversion. I also explained that he isn't changing every value in the input list, so that is probably why there are string values.

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant.OP is trying to print the `type` not the value itself plus OP stats that he can see values in the list as `Int` when printing the list itself.

Comment: @Himal The OP is specifically asking for how to get integers. "I need it to be an int like I assigned it too." His print is probably happening from printing a single character from string. I am not sure as to his problems with printing. I am simply trying to solve his problem of getting the integer that he wants. I have edited the answer to explain that he is trying to loop through a string like it is a list.

Comment: Further, you've answered in a way that is completely counter-intuitive to the question.  You're answering taking into account the first 3 values in my_list, when the OP obviously drops them from the working list.